# Enable / Disable Tips for series (in chart) at runtime

Tags: extjs, charts, series

I have a chart-->Series-->Tips

How can I disable/hide the tips at run time? As the user wishes (enable / disable)

Comment: yes. see my link: http://forums.unigui.com/index.php?/topic/2769-charts-gradient-color-animate-using-unigui/

Comment: The link is broken: "The community administrator requires all members to sign in"